# Github Actions deploying docker to package | Error: not found: python

Tags: node.js, docker, github-actions

I'm trying to setup Github Actions to build a docker package and I'm running into this error:

```
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
```

Workflow step:

```
    - name: Publish to Github Packages Registry
      uses: elgohr/Publish-Docker-Github-Action@master
      with:
        name: SimpleAdminTeam/Website-Client/src
        registry: docker.pkg.github.com
        username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        dockerfile: Dockerfile-prod
        tags: latest
```

I'm using latest stable Node.JS, node-sass, and node-gyp versions. Any help would really be appreciated as I've been crawling the web for a while now trying to figure it out. If you need any more info, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your DockerFile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python
```

Comment: What base docker image are you using? apt-get is a package manager for linux.